# BASH script using arrays to store commands for looped execution fails due to wildcards and other special chars

Tags: arrays, bash, expansion

I am trying to write a BASH script that will execute hundreds of commands. I decided to store all of these commands into arrays, and then execute them in a loop. Unfortunately, some of the commands are not executing correctly because of expansion.

I have tried utilizing escape characters, with varying degrees of success. arr1 now works correctly thanks to \'s, but arr's 2 and 3 don't work due to the * wildcard.

I've tried using set -f -p -P -C -u -B, as well as shopt nullglob and shopt globstar.

Everything I've read emphasizes using double quotes when calling the arrays and variables, which I've done. I'm beginning to think that using arrays was not the best idea, but I'm also confident that using set/shopt could create an environment that would allow the commands to be expanded out of the array without using escape characters. Any guidance or suggestions for other solutions would be very much appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=""
set -fvP

declare -a arr1=("38499" "awk -F: '(\$2 != \"x\") {print}' /etc/passwd" "If it produces any output, then a password hash is stored in /etc/passwd.If any stored hashes are found in /etc/passwd, this is a finding")

declare -a arr2=("38624" "grep logrotate /var/log/cron*" "If the logrotate service is not run on a daily basis by cron, this is a finding")

declare -a arr3=("38696" "grep aide /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*" "If there is no output, this is a finding")

declare -a arr4=("38697" "find [PART] -xdev -type d -perm -002 \! -perm -1000" "If any world-writable directories are missing the sticky bit, this is a finding")

declare -a arr5=("38498" "grep ^log_file /etc/audit/auditd.conf|sed s/^[^\/]*//|xargs stat -c %a:%n" "Audit logs must be mode 0640 or less permissive. If any are more permissive, this is a finding")


for (( i=1; i<=5; i+=1 ));
do
    arrnum="arr$i[0]"
    arrcommand="arr$i[1]"
    arroutput="arr$i[2]"
    echo $i
        echo "Vulnerability #: " "${!arrnum}"
    echo "Command is: " "${!arrcommand}"
    echo "Output Expected: " "${!arroutput}"
    read -p "Perform this command?" -n 1 -r
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        echo "Performing command"
        eval sudo "${!arrcommand}"
        echo 
        echo
    fi
done
```

Comment: Don't store commands in variables. Take a look at [Bash FAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more info.

Comment: Can u not store commands in a text file and  then call the file instead of array?

Comment: Using a table-driven approach for this is a good idea, but trying to put non-trivial commands in strings is a bad idea.  Mixing `eval` and `sudo` is a very bad idea. One possible way to make the basic idea work is to define a function for each of the vulnerability checks and modify the table so that it contains function names instead of commands.